# Why is くれる used here and not あげる

Tags: meaning, usage, subsidiary-verbs

The lines are taken from a visual novel and the translation as well

Example 1

> 逃れるつもり ?
> 逃れる? 違うな世界の終焉までに時間をくれてやろうというのだ
> What are you running away?
> Run? No. I'm simply giving you time to enjoy until the end of the world

Example 2

> でも彼らたちに悪感情もってくれたのは好都合かもしれないよね
> It might be good that we left them with such a bad taste in their mouth

Example 3

> 許さんぞ
> そこに直れ. 成敗してくれる
> I'll never forgive you
> Prepare yourself
> I will defeat you today

So くれる is supposed to be used when someone is doing something for the speaker. When you're doing something for someone else you're supposed to use あげる. So why is is that here くれる is used? Does it have to do with the perspective?

Comment: Reverse usage of くれる expresses 尊大法 (arrogant mood) for the subject, in other words, derogatory towards the object (though example 2 is a normal usage; "it might be good (for us) that s/he had bad impression to them").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to note that the verb *くれる* is not always used when someone else does something to the speaker. It is rare though but it could be used when the speaker does something to someone else, especially when it is combined with やる (to do, to undertake). For example:

> そんな[物]{もの}、[呉]{く}れてやれ. (Literally and imperative) Give such a thing
> (to someone else)
>
> [乞食]{こじき}に[銭]{ぜに}を[呉]{く}れてやる. (Literally) (I) give a small money
> (coin) to a beggar.

When you use *くれる* with やる, it sounds a little belittling and pejorative.

Also, you should note that *くれる* is a non-honorific form of [[下]{くだ}さる](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84).

When to use くれる in place of あげる is not very easy to understand. But you should note that it is not common and it has a belittling and pejorative connotation.

Comment: やる's original meaning is "to give, to send".

Comment: "くれる is a non-honorific form of **下さる**" の間違いでは？