# Using てくれる instead of てあげる when performing an action towards someone

Tags: grammar

I was reading the `Bleach` manga and found this odd structure I am not used to.

One (giant) character is about to squish another character with his hands when he says:

> [image]

I didn't know you could use `てくれる` when performing an action for/against someone.

if he said:

> 握り潰してやる or 握り潰してあげる

It would've made sense to me, but I don't get `くれる` used in this context.

Comment: @aguijonazo I tried searching for answers explaining this, but could not find it. This one you linked and this one: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40560/16104 cleared my doubts. 

It is shortened version of くれてやる which is an arrogant/pejorative version of あげる. Thank you!

Comment: Should I delete the question?!

Comment: [You should *not* delete a duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-good-duplicates).